# Deneb: combining Power BI tooltip with custom mouseover behavior

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I'm working on a report design, which has quite specific requirements for chart behavior. Using Deneb, I've created small multiples looking like this, with bars/labels being some sort of KPI, and number below is calendar week:

[image]

Using param with select / mouseover I've managed to dynamically change label. Here's my param code:

```
        "params": [
          {
            "name": "displayOnHover",
            "select": {
              "type": "point",
              "fields": [
                "Calendarweek"
              ],
              "toggle": false,
              "nearest": false,
              "on": "mouseover",
              "clear": "mouseout"
            }
          }
        ]
```

And here's my filter code on label text mark:

```
          {
            "filter": {
              "param": "displayOnHover",
              "empty": false
            }
          }
```

So all my label change based on which calendar week is being hovered over in barchart. So far, so good. However, there's another requirement. I need to display tooltip for label, and tooltip is another page in Power BI.

My label mark:

```
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "align": "center",
          "dy": -50,
          "fontSize": 21,
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "tooltip": true
        }
```

My tooltip settings:
[image]

Weirdly, tooltip works properly when hovering over barchart (also with tooltip: true in mark), but not for label unless I remove displayOnHover param.

Also I've tried adding another layered mark that wouldn't be filtered by displayOnHover, and it doesn't display tooltip as well, unless I remove displayOnHover param from bar.

Comment: Can you supply a working .pbix and clarify your expected results?

Comment: Sure, I'll prepare it later today (it's for commercial project so I need to recreate it on different dataset). 

As for expected results: 
- Power BI tooltip, defined in options, should be showing up when hovering the label (which it, currently, doesn't)
- label should remain dynamic, based on which bar user is hovering over in barchart, via param (it works)